# Надо ли на каждом php файле закрывать соединение с mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Надо ли на каждом php файле закрывать соединение с mysql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соединение закрывается автоматически при завершении работы скрипта, хотя советуют не особо надеятся на автоматизм PHP и закрывать ручками. Выбор сугубо за вами.

Comment: И вообще, привычка убирать за собой -- полезная привычка.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал ручками закрывать, в коде php. Как то зашел на сервер БД, на сайт, где в коде не закрывал подключение, так там 90% уведомлений было на счет того что "некорректно закрыто подключение", прописал в код закрытие, и подобных сообщений больше не возникает.

p.s. смотрел через phpMyAdmin